# What order are Tomcat Realm methods called in?

Tags: java, tomcat7

On the project I am working on we have a corporate LDAP server and a custom cache that stores tokens, provides sessions etc, and a library is available for connecting to it and authenticating by sending it a username and password and it returns a boolean and a list of roles. Since we will be using Tomcat for our web application I decided to create my own Tomcat Realm that will use this library to authenticate users.

Reading through various posts etc, one of the recommendations was to extend RealmBase (instead of just implementing Realm and overriding all required methods) so I have done that. But I have a question on exactly which methods I need to override, and what order they will be called in by Tomcat.

```
public Principal authenticate(String username, String credentials) { /* */ }
```

This one seems like the only one I should need for basic authentication - a user types in their username and password, and if this method does not return null, they are authenticated. Is this correct? Will Tomcat try and call all the various different 'authenticate' methods until it finds one that works? How does the overloading work in this case?

I am also curious about this method:

```
protected String getPassword(String username) { /* */ }
```

The library we are using takes in a username and password, and tells me whether the user is authenticated or not - I do not have access to retrieve the stored password for the user. But I cannot leave this method out, or compilation fails because I haven't implemented required methods. Can I just leave this method in, and get it to return null? Or is there a better way? If this method is only used by Tomcat *after* the authenticate method is called, then I can save the password from that method. Would this work?

Comment: By connecting a debugger to my Realm it seems that the 'getPassword' method is indeed not called (or at least it isn't called before 'authenticate(username, password)'

Answer (score 0):

They are called in the order implied by the order of their appearance in `server.xml,` the global `context.xml,` and webapp-specific `context.xml` files.

Comment: I am specifically curious about the methods inside a realm, rather than multiple realms. Extending 'RealmBase' forces me to implement the 'getPassword(username)' method, but I have no way of retrieving the password for a user, so I need to know if I can leave this method blank. I read somewhere that this method is necessary, and that Tomcat will not continue to the 'authenticate' method if the password returned does not match the user password, but I see in the JNDIRealm source that this returns null for 'getPassword'